# Cordova iOS - Build App Error 65

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, xcodebuild

I developed an App on a Windows Machine (For Android).
I also want the App for iOS. So I installed Xcode, node.js and cordova.
There are no errors, when I run my App on a Emulator.
When I run the App on Device with the command `cordova run ios --device`, I get the following Errors:

```
Check dependencies
Signing for "HelloCordova" requires a development team. Select a development     team in the project editor.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'

** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -    
xcconfig,/Users/milkogrieger/Woow2/platforms/ios/cordova/build-
debug.xcconfig,-    workspace,HelloCordova.xcworkspace,-scheme,HelloCordova,-
configuration,Debug,-    
destination,generic/platform=iOS,-  
archivePath,HelloCordova.xcarchive,archive,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/milkogri
eger/Woow2/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/milkogrieger/Woow2/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

I found the following Solutions and tried them:

- remove all plugins
- add plugins
- remove platforms
- add platforms

But the error is still there.

I hope someone can help me

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify your development team as the message indicates. You can do this easily by configuring `build.json`, as described [in the docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/index.html#using-buildjson) and [further clarified here](https://dpogue.ca/articles/cordova-xcode8.html).

Comment: Same fix has been described also at apache ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12249